# C# database application

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ado.net

here's my code

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Date] FROM [dbo].[DS_PROJECT] ORDER BY Date ASC", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Time] FROM [dbo].[DS_PROJECT] ORDER BY Time ASC", con);
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
DateTime currenttime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime userdate = Convert.ToDateTime(cmd);
DateTime usertime = Convert.ToDateTime(cm);
```

i want to convert the date and time values saved in my database  but am unable to do it and this exception occurs

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' to
>   type 'System.IConvertible

Please Help me.
Thank You

Comment: Hi Ali, `ExecuteNonQuery` should be used for SQL commands that modify data (e.g. Inserts, Updates, Deletes). If you want to read data you should use `ExecuteReader` instead. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You get data by using `ExecuteReader` method of a `SqlCommand` and take data from the data reader it returns. There is a simple example on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteReader).

Comment: Sorry... what??? First you execute a query as non-query. Then you try to convert the query object to a value it should return. Start here: https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldatareader

Comment: Also, if you want to get one and only one value from a SQL query you should use `ExecuteScalar` method, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using ExecuteNonQuery() is intended for UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE queries that shouldn't return a value or a record set.

You can use ExecuteReader() to retrive multiple data records.

If you want to query for just a single value, you should use:

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Note : Check for null first as it can return a a null reference if the result set is empty.

Answer (score 0):

cm.ExecuteNonQuery()

The method is guess is not correct as per

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

ExecuteNonQuery() returns the number of rows affected. Also the method is generally used when executing insert update or delete query. 
To get the result from the select statement, use the following blog by MSDN.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it should be a comment instead.

Comment: can you edit the code , i am trying but there i am unable to do it?

Comment: @RuiJarimba I recently joined Stackoverflow and do not have enough rewards to comment. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, ExecuteNonQuery is used for the insert as well as update statement. You can use DataSet or DataReader , if you will have get multiple values from the database. 
Here in your case if you are using the query for single value retrieval, then you can use the ExecuteScalar menthod. which will return single value from the database. May be the below link will helpful..

http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-sqlcommand-executescalar.htm